# How to use SDWebImage to download and save CGImage

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

I'm trying to use SDWebImage to download and image from an external url and return it. I do not want to set it on a view. This is the code I'm using, but it's not working. I'm returning nil. But I know the url I'm passing in works because I can see it in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

```
func downloadImage() -> CGImage {
   var myImage: CGImage?
   let myUrl = URL(string: "my-url-here.com")

   SDWebImageDownloader.shared.downloadImage(with: myUrl, completed: { (image, data, error, true) in
       print("Completed")
       if image != nil {
           myImage = image?.cgImage
       }
   })

   return myImage!
}
```

I also tried this version, also with no luck:

```
func downloadImage() -> CGImage {
    var myImage: CGImage?
    let myUrl = URL(string: "my-url-here.com")

    SDWebImageManager.shared.loadImage(with: myUrl, options: .continueInBackground, progress: { (received, expected, nil) in
        print(received, expected)
    }, completed: { (downloadedImage, data, error, SDImageCacheType, true, imageUrlString) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if downloadedImage != nil {
                myImage = downloadedImage?.cgImage
            }
        }
    })

    return myImage!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDWebImage is an asynchronous library. You can’t just `return` the results. Generally one would use an `@escaping` closure to supply the results to the caller. E.g.

```
func downloadImage(completion: @escaping(CGImage?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://my-url-here.com")!

    SDWebImageDownloader.shared.downloadImage(with: url) { image, _, _, _ in
        completion(image?.cgImage)
    }
}
```

And you’d use it like:

```
downloadImage { image in
    guard let image = image else { return }

    // use image here
}

// but not here
```

---

But let’s step back and look at the whole pattern. You say you want to “save” the result. If you’re talking about saving it to persistent storage, you would not want to use `CGImage` (or `UIImage` or whatever) at all. That’s computationally inefficient (converting asset to image and then back to `Data` so you can save it), space inefficient (you have to load the whole asset into memory at the same time), and likely introduces problems (e.g. if you download a JPG, convert to `CGImage` and then try to recreate a JPG, the resulting asset will be slightly different, bigger, and/or with new JPG artifacts). If you’re just pre-downloading assets, just use a simple networking library like Alamofire or `URLSession`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually trying to download the image to use as a texture in Metal. So I need a CGImage to pass to Metal. Or it will allow me to pass Data. I'm still a fairly new developer - any ideas on how I can better do this?

Comment: OK, if you need to use the `CGImage`, then by all means, do that. But if you’re don’t really need the `CGImage` at this point and are just turning around and saving it to persistent storage, then you should likely avoid the roundtrip to `CGImage`. Use your own good judgment. (I only mention it because I’ve seen more than one StackOverflow question where someone downloads an image, creates a JPG or PNG representation, and saves it to storage, which is horribly inefficient process. But if that’s not what you’re doing, then ignore my caveat at the end of my answer.)

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for the example and the explanation!!